# Dynamic bodies falling onto static body tunnel through each other or fail to bounce

Tags: physics, box2d, collision-resolution, physics-engine, swift

I have a problem with Box2D when 2 dynamic bodies fall onto a static body located below when their restitution is non-zero. They tunnel through each other instead of a rigid elastic bounce.

If I treat the two falling bodies as bullets, they don't tunnel, but instead stop dead with no bounce.

Everything works correctly when the bottom body is not static.

[image: Large body falling onto a smaller body falling onto another large body]

[Video demonstrating the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IOUFa.jpg)

How can I get the expected behaviour?

I am using Swift port of Box2D version 2.3.1.

Comment: This is one of those problems - especially when the object in the middle of the stack has much less mass than the ones around it - that game physics engines are notoriously bad at solving the way we'd like them to. [This talk from Bennett Foddy explains why](https://gdcvault.com/play/1021921/Designing-with-Physics-Bend-the) (at 11 & 16 minutes in). The reason it seems to work better with the dynamic body on the bottom is actually the same tunneling problem on the right: the small body tunnels into the body beneath, which then pushes it out gradually so the top body has time to move away.

Comment: Thank you. However, I looked into similar games such as Incredibots, which use older version of Box2D and their source is publicly available. I didn't see such problems occurring in the very same setting.